# Android: Launching Home Screen in Android 4.0

Tags: android, homescreen

I am trying to launch the home screen from a service.. I used the following code

```
           Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
           startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(startMain);
```

It is working fine in Android 2.3, but not in 4.0

In 4.0 its showing a list to choose what should be a default screen.

I need the same effect as we can get in 2.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this add see if it works.

instead of this Category,  `startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`

try this,

```
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

Comment: Thank u sir it worked :) i ll check this answer in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

The homescreen can be triggered from your manifest.
start your Activity, you want to have as homescreen like following:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.HomeScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you want to switch to the next Screen after an amount of Milliseconds, create your Activity like following:

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 3000; // time to display the splash screen in ms

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Your Activity Title");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    // thread for displaying the HomeScreen
    Thread homeTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.SecondViewActivity"));
            }
        }
    };
    homeTread.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```